# How to add logic to PHPBB template file?

Tags: php, phpbb

How do we apply logic in template file of phpBB?
The way they have taught in the tutorial doesnt works for me.
I have used this:

```
$template->assign_var('POINTER',$pointer);
```

and in the .tpl file

```
!-- IF POINTER == 1 -->
  do this  
!-- ELSE -->
  do that  
!--  ENDIF -->
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Are you using PHPBB3 or 2? Because the IF-Condtion exists only in Version 3.

2.) You know that the "<"-Sign is missing at the begin of your Code?

Comment: How do i know which version is this..I was just handed this code 2 days back and i think by the code that its PHPBB.

Comment: look at the first lines of your index.php in your phpBB installation - if it says @package phpBB3 then you have got phpBB3 - i think you should find the version in the admin interface as well...

Comment: I dont find anything in index.php but in a file template.php under class directory i saw 
// template.php
// copyright            : (C) 2001 The phpBB Group that is why i concluded it to be a phpbb code.Now i am not sure if this is even phpBB.

Comment: Then i would guess, someone implemented the phpBB-Template engine in a custom script/cms. Never the less, (C) 2001 does not look like phpBB3 - so you need to put your logic to the controller/php-file and use the template only for output...

Comment: means i cant apply any if else conditions in tempalates?

Comment: i dont think so, but you can put the if-condition in your php file and show or hide blocks in the template.

Comment: Okay Nebel,Thanx for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code:

```
// There wasn't anything wrong with the PHP code
$pointer = 1;
$template->assign_var('POINTER', $pointer);
```

In the template file:

```
<!-- IF POINTER == 1 -->
    <div>Pointer is 1</div>  
<!-- ELSE -->
    <div>Pointer is not 1</div>  
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

**Errors:**

1. HTML comments (and phpBB instruction blocks) start with `<!--`
2. There's only one space after `<!--` (you had two for `ENDIF`)